# Should we ask for tag warnings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

In [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237), it is mentioned that SE has recently introduced "tag warnings" in SO, which are meant to alert users about things they should be doing in the course of adding tags to their question. Here is a relevant screenshot:

[image: tag warning example]

On account of most users not bothering to read tag wikis (:P) when tagging their questions, a popup alerting users about a tag they have added might be useful.

The obvious candidate in our site, of course, would be [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs); a tag warning can remind the user not to add the tag when first posting.

If you think there are other tags that need a tag warning, write an answer with the tag name, the proposed warning text in a block quote, and some context.

Feedback on whether we should ask for this feature or not is also welcome.

Comment: The `Plotting` - `Graphics`- `Graph` triad get often confused

Comment: @bel, then propose tag warnings for those, and we can then polish or critique it!

Answer (score 23):

[bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs)

> Do not add the [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag to your question until your observations have been confirmed by other users or Wolfram Technical Support.

Related thread: [How to report bugs?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190)

Comment: This is an example answer for suggesting tags that might benefit from having tag warnings. Of course, if you have a better proposal for the associated popup in mind, please edit this answer.

Comment: Actually, we kind of had the rule that it needs to be confirmed by WRI to be tagged as bug, but I break this sometimes myself, when I'm sure I found a bug. I think that's reasonable when it is clear that an issue is unlikely to be a feature [like here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89156/187). Nevertheless, this warning is a very good idea.

Comment: Perhaps this warning should also mention that if a bug is suspected the question should be tagged with a version tag?

Comment: @halirutan I believe we agreed to tag with bugs if a few community members could confirm the behavior and in fact agree it's a bug.

Comment: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/354/how-should-the-bug-tag-be-used

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Then my memory failed me. Maybe I remembered the "confirmed bugs" expression that Szabolcs used, maybe something else. Anyway, thanks for digging this out.

Answer (score 17):

[windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows)

> Only use the [windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag if you have evidence to believe that
>   your question is related to this specific OS. Do **NOT** use it to
>   simply indicate the OS you are currently using. You could provide that
>   information in the body of your question.

[osx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx)

> Only use the [osx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag if you have evidence to believe that
>   your question is related to this specific OS. Do **NOT** use it to
>   simply indicate the OS you are currently using. You could provide that
>   information in the body of your question.

[linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux)

> Only use the [linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag if you have evidence to believe that
>   your question is related to this specific OS. Do **NOT** use it to
>   simply indicate the OS you are currently using. You could provide that
>   information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 10):

[version-6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6)

> Do **NOT** use the [version-6](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6) tag in bug reporting. If you are
>   posting about apparent bugs, provide the Mathematica version(s) in
>   which you are seeing your issues in the body of your question and when
>   more information becomes available use or update the header as
>   described in [this Meta
>   post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

[version-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7)

> Do **NOT** use the [version-7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7) tag in bug reporting. If you are
>   posting about apparent bugs, provide the Mathematica version(s) in
>   which you are seeing your issues in the body of your question and when
>   more information becomes available use or update the header as
>   described in [this Meta
>   post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

[version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8)

> Do **NOT** use the [version-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-8) tag in bug reporting. If you are
>   posting about apparent bugs, provide the Mathematica version(s) in
>   which you are seeing your issues in the body of your question and when
>   more information becomes available use or update the header as
>   described in [this Meta
>   post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

[version-9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-9)

> Do **NOT** use the [version-9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-9) tag in bug reporting. If you are
>   posting about apparent bugs, provide the Mathematica version(s) in
>   which you are seeing your issues in the body of your question and when
>   more information becomes available use or update the header as
>   described in [this Meta
>   post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

[version-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-10)

> Do **NOT** use the [version-10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-10) tag in bug reporting. If you are
>   posting about apparent bugs, provide the Mathematica version(s) in
>   which you are seeing your issues in the body of your question and when
>   more information becomes available use or update the header as
>   described in [this Meta
>   post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

BTW: there are more [version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version) tags.

Comment: Hmm, I'm honestly not sure if tag warnings will support links. Do you have an alternate in case they don't? (Probably better to wait for an SE employee to comment, tho.)

Comment: You could always post the link as text, I guess.

Comment: I see a pattern there ;-)

Comment: @Yves, wouldn't it be hilarious if there *weren't*? :)

Comment: @YvesKlett yeah, it's a bit of a page filler this way, but I thought it better to explicitly specify the tags and texts so that SE developers don't have to be aware of the relevant versions if and when they will be working with this

Comment: BTW the policy to not include a version tag when reporting bugs is discussed [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1364/57) and the answer has an upvote count of 25 at the moment. I'm a bit surprised that the above answer that implements this policy only receives one upvote.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries of course - I was just quipping, no critique whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

[matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)

> The [matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag is intended only for questions on interfacing *Mathematica* with MATLAB, or emulating MATLAB constructs in *Mathematica*. Any other question is off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

[wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud)

> Only use the [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud) tag for questions specific to Wolfram Cloud products. Do **NOT** use it to simply indicate that you are using the Wolfram Language within one of these products, as this information should be provided in the body of the question.

Answer (score 4):

[webmathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webmathematica)

> Only use the [webmathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webmathematica) tag for questions specific to web*Mathematica*. Do **NOT** use it to simply indicate in which interface the Wolfram Language code will be used. It should not be confused with the [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud) tag.