# Should we change the "bugs" tag name to something like "confirmed-bugs"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'm getting  little bit tired of finding the

> Please don't use the BUGS tag until the community find confirmation there is a bug

comment under most [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) questions.

Comment: If we are going to do this I propose we alias Bugs with Unconfirmed-bugs

Comment: Hey, I wrote that! Sorry...  :)

Comment: @rhermans  Ego te absolvo a peccatis tuis in nomine Patris et Filii etc.:)

Answer (score 9):

### Update:

- Moderator-only tags are probably a no-go, and probably not the best idea anyway.
- [Tag Warnings](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1720/18476) are a great idea IMO and I have requested their implementation on our site.
- If Tag Warnings are not enough I propose [possible-bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possible-bug) and [confirmed-bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confirmed-bug) as replacements.

---

Interesting proposal.  I don't really like making tag names needlessly longer, but I seem to recall that you were the first to propose `wolfram-mathematica` on Stack Overflow and later it became apparent such a change was in fact beneficial.

As it stands we have the tag summary:

> This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

I guess the question is how many people actually read that, and how many ignore it?  I don't have those numbers.  If people are reading this and applying the tag anyway I don't think it will matter what we name the tag.

I wonder of some tags should be moderator-only, like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) here on meta.  I don't know if this is possible, and I cannot recall reading about this on the main meta site but I shall look for it.

If it *is* possible to make [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs), [faq](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), etc. only applicable by moderators is that a good solution?  This would increase the workload for moderators, but at the moment it seems we are not having trouble handing flags, etc. in a timely fashion.

Comment: Nice, And how do you propose the mods to be notified of  a candidate? Via flags?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Is "nice" facetious here?  Yes, I guess a flag would be needed if one of us did not come across the question in the regular course of events.  As I said it would increase the moderator workload but it would firmly prevent this tag from being misapplied, whereas I can *easily* imagine some users throwing on `confirmed-bugs` because it is *confirmed in their own mind.*

Comment: I think the idea of mods-managed tags is "nice". No pun intended.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius  Okay, more internet ambiguity.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: As the guy who has to deal with a lot of tagging stuff, I'm sure that unless [tag:bugs] can be restricted in some way (e.g. the mod only idea), users old and new will keep putting it on questions that haven't yet gone through community vetting. So, the additional "confirmed" really won't do much, unless we can find some magical incantation that will hypnotically force people to read tag wikis.

Comment: Did the moderators ask for [tag warnings](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1720/18476)?

Comment: @J.M. The same kind of arguments were used before (ie. people won't read it, no matter what). I believe that putting the keyword as a second word on the tag and using another strong word as first (in this case my try is "confirmed", but could be another one, and more explicit) force more people into thinking what they are doing

Comment: I support  [tag:Bug?] available to all, and [tag:Bug-Confirmed] for users with some reputation including a *Tag-waring* explaining the rules.

Comment: @Karsten Tag Warnings were apparently proposed while I was taking somewhat of a break from Stack Exchange.  That seems like an excellent first step.  Let me see if I can get this done.

Comment: @rhermans I'm pretty sure `?` is not allowed in tag names.  What about `possible-bug` and `confirmed-bug` if the Tag Warnings don't get the job done?

Comment: I like your updated suggestions. No pun intended. Just in case

Comment: Maybe make [tag:bugs] a synonim that defaults to [tag:possible-bug] ?

Comment: @shrx I am trying to remember if that is possible.  The existing questions with the `bugs` tag are `confirmed-bug` and I would need to make sure that I don't accidentally change all of those to `possible-bug`.  I *think* this can be done in two steps but I don't believe I've ever done this particular operation and I wouldn't want to make a mess of it.

Comment: It seems we still don't have Tag Warnings yet, which is not surprising as the developers are busy people and it is currently and manual operation.  I think I should probably wait for that before making other tag changes.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes (why didn't we do this years ago?)

It's 2020 and people keep tagging unconfirmed bugs as [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) every month or so. Some examples:

- [Compile and uncompilable function bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149343/compile-and-uncompilable-function-bug)
- [Why does NumberForm disturb the output of Rationalize?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203690/why-does-numberform-disturb-the-output-of-rationalize)
- [Why is MemoryInUse[] Very Different from the Actual Amount of Memory Being Used?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217086/why-is-memoryinuse-very-different-from-the-actual-amount-of-memory-being-used)
- [Have I found bugs in Solve and Reduce?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195214/have-i-found-bugs-in-solve-and-reduce)
- [Mathematica v12 Integration bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209221/mathematica-v12-integration-bug)
- [Possible bug involving derivative of BesselI](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215122/possible-bug-involving-derivative-of-besseli)
- [Possible bug in Solve function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188900/possible-bug-in-solve-function)
- [Possible Symbolic Integration Bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156215/possible-symbolic-integration-bug)
- [Summation bug in 11.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157290/summation-bug-in-11-2)
- [Does AroundReplace work with Quantity?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217192/does-aroundreplace-work-with-quantity)
- [EMF Export Bug in v12](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195387/emf-export-bug-in-v12)
- [FullSimplify output depends on symbol name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206897/fullsimplify-output-depends-on-symbol-name)
- [Wrong function of NotebookDirectory[] in the 12.1 version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219700)

and [dozens more](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amathematica.stackexchange.com+Please+do+not+use+the+bugs+tag+when+posting+new+questions). It is clear to me that the meaning of [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) is contrary to what new users expect from a tag called "bugs", and most users do not read the tag description to correct themselves. [Other users](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2308/suspected-bug-tag#comment9849_2308) have noted the same problem. The name [confirmed-bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confirmed-bug) would *actually mean what people expect it to*, so renaming it seems like an obvious choice, even if it does not dissuade users from tagging new questions [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) all the time.

Comment: I also think "vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug" is rather vague. The tag wiki should have some clear guideline like "one other user can reproduce and agrees this is a bug" or "confirmed by either a moderator or a WRI employee". But that's a separate issue.