# Suspected-bug Tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think the number one place where visitors to the MSE get peeved is with our usage of [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs)

They find something that doesn't work and then quite reasonably attach [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs), but then we come in and say, "We prefer to only label those things as bugs which have been confirmed with WRI". Both sides of the coin are valid in my mind and I think we should stick with our community convention, but I wonder if it's worth creating [suspected-bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspected-bug) or similar to handle cases where confirmation with WRI has not yet been obtained.

This may have been proposed before. I couldn't see it explicitly in the titles of any of the questions here. Worth bringing up again, at the minimum, though.

Comment: I think the standard so far has been "confirmed by the community", not "confirmed by WRI" and that makes more sense to me. If the issue is not really a bug, but a user misunderstanding, the experienced people here are quick in pointing it out. A support case number, or the support engineer's opinion, do not necessarily reflect the true status of a bug which is more in the domain of QA and R&D.

Comment: As noted by @ilian, a suspected bug should not be tagged as such until "confirmed by the community".  But, what constitutes confirmation? Do any guidelines exist?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Well, it seems to me that one guideline is that confirmed-by-WRI is sufficient :-)

Comment: Loose thoughts: I have mixed feelings about this. I was thinking about `fixed-bug` status/tag lately. There is also a combination of documentation+bugs. Or what about bugs in 3rd part packages? So there are clearly couple of types/states of bugs we are interested in. How to handle all of that in a consistent way, without using 2 tags per question, or without worrying about a flood of misplaced tags. There are voices saying this is not a place for a bug tracker which I think I agree with, otoh I would love to have one here :P

Answer (score 3):

I moved my old answer to a separate topic: [Standard header for bugs-tagged posts V2](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2310/5478)

---

I don't think it will help with anything. What is the difference whether you tell OP to "not use bugs until it is confirmed" or "use suspected-bug until it is confirmed"?

And who will take care about cleaning up after this stage?

I think there should be only one tag: [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) alternatively we can [extend standard header](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2310/5478)